# My Watering System Tap Timer is leaking - how to fix? What part is missing?

Tags: watering

Got home a few days ago and my Tap Timer was flooding the garden :( I'm stuck trying to figure out what is actually wrong, though.

The product is a [Holman's Bluetooth Tap Timer](https://www.holmanindustries.com.au/products/bluetooth-tap-timer-co3015/).

[Here is a video of me trying to connect the Tap Timer to my water plug](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3BLSovGKgS8).

I'm just not sure why it's suddenly not 'locking'. I can definately take more photo's of the Tap Timer, but I need some help in trying to debug this problem.

Does anyone have some ideas about what I might be missing? Or what I have done wrong?

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]